# troubleshoot failed cloudwatch events

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-batch

This part of cloudformation template creates the event, but do not actually execute it.

```
  MyCWEventRule:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties: 
      Name: my-batch-event-rule
      ScheduleExpression: cron(01 07 ? * * *)
      State: ENABLED
      Targets: 
        - Id: my-batch-job
          Arn: !Ref Queue
          BatchParameters: 
            JobDefinition: !Ref StartJob
            JobName: tds-job
          RoleArn: !Join [ "", [!Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/service-role/", !Ref ruleIAMRole]]
```

There are no logs to check what the problem is. If I submit the job myself using console, it works as expected.
The Job Definition parameter mentioned in cron is correct as seen in this image...

[image]

How do I troubleshoot failed cloudwatch events?

---

Update:

When I click on Edit and use "Create a new role for this specific resource" it works.
It means there is some problem with the line...

> RoleArn: !Join [ "", [!Sub
> "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/service-role/", !Ref
> ruleIAMRole]]

Comment: I can see "Monitoring: Show Metrics for the rule" link in the image. If I click on that, I am told that the job was invoked and failed. But without any details how will I know the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You guessed it right! There is no need of "service-role" in the ARN role path. It should look like this...

```
RoleArn: !Join [ "", [!Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/", !Ref ruleIAMRole]]
```

Or even better:

```
RoleArn: !GetAtt ruleIAMRole.Arn
```